# Reading Configuration value via Rest Webservices

Tags: java, web-services, rest, configuration

My application has two parts:

1. Backend which majorly consisting of Rest Web services which talks to DB and get the Data.
2. FrontEnd, displays the data retrieved from webservices call based on business logic.

They both sit in different servers/environment.

Due to data issues, we keep changing the regions(alpha,beta,gamma,prod) and one of the requirement right now is to show the region on UI, so QA can know, against what region they are doing testing.

This can be achieved by making a webservice call from UI and get the region back(implementation in webservices) but I don't want to invoke the webservice if we can achieve by setting some global configuration?

Also, the region is being shown in main page, so if page changes/refreshed it will make webservices just to get that string (region).

I thought to club with existing call but there is lots of changes due to below change.

```
modelAndView.setView(jsonView_i);
if (!myList.isEmpty())
  modelAndView.addObject("DATA_FIELD", myList);

SQLMapProperties prop = new SQLMapProperties();
String configuredRegion= prop.getProperty("region");
modelAndView.addObject("region", configuredRegion);
```

Can anyone help me with some solution on above to achieve this? How about using some Spring configuration/Servlet? How can I just read this region once from webservices and set into application scope.